# JUnit for final method of abstract class

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermock

I am having trouble writing a JUnit test. The issue is that there is a final method `getMessage()` in the following block of code:

```
if(these_conditions_are_true) {
    String message = messageResources.getMessage(CONSTANT_STRING, null, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());
    modelView.getModelMap().addAttribute(INLINE_MSG, message);
    return modelView;
}
```

`messsageResources` is a `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` which extends `AbstractMessageSource`, which is an abstract class.

`getMessage()` is a final method in `AbstractMessageSource`.

Here is the condensed version of my Test class:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({AbstractMessageSource.class, ClassBeingTested.class})
public class ClassBeingTestedTest {

@InjectMocks
ClassBeingTested classBeingTested;


@Mock
ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageResources; //being used by a different test in this class, including in case it matters

@Before
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    // Build the mock
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(classBeingTested).build();
}

@Test
public void Method_Being_Tested_Test() {
    AbstractMessageSource amsMock = PowerMockito.mock(AbstractMessageSource.class);     
    Mockito.when(amsMock.getMessage(any(), any(), any())).thenReturn("test01"); 
    ModelAndView mv = classBeingTested.methodBeingTested(itemVO);

    ModelAndView mv_Expected = createExpectedMV(); //not really how i'm doing it, but for the sake of simplicity i'll omit it

    assertEquals(mv_Expected, mv); 
}

}
```

I'm using PowerMockito since I learned that Mockito can't stub final methods.

The error I get is

> No message found under code 'CONSTANT_STRING' for locale 'EN_US'.

It appears that my `when`...`thenReturn` isn't actually being used as `getMessage()` is being called. I've tried adding `CALLS_REAL_METHOD` to the line where I create the Mock, but that didn't seem to work.

Does anyone know how to stub this out? Am I right to mock `AbstractMessageSource`, rather than `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource`? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE:

I'm still looking for help with this. I'm still running into the issue of not being able to intercept `getMessage()` actually being called...

Comment: Use MessageSource as the type of classA. Program to interfaces, not implementations.

Comment: Is this a Spring Boot app or at least a SpringWebMVC app? I'd recommend not doing any of this. If you are spending more time trying to test the implementation with some pretty extreme test code. There is bound to be other ways to test this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Mockito.when(
    amsMock.getMessage(
        eq(CONSTANT_STRING),
        eq(null),
        any(Locale.class))).thenReturn("test01");
```

Edit: This strategy is terrible,
because you will need to mock the `getMessage` method for every property that is accessed during your unit test.

What you appear to want is the ability to set a property value for use during your unit tests.
If this is the case,
include a property configuration for your unit tests.
For spring,
you can create a unit test configuration that references the test properties and load it with the SpringRunner.

Comment: Still getting this error: "org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'validation.js.register.phoneNumber' for locale 'en_US'.
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractMessageSource.getMessage(AbstractMessageSource.java:159)"

Comment: so, instead of "still getting", you appear to mean "That worked, but now I'm getting".  Is that the case?

Comment: Sorry. After implementing what you suggested, I am still getting the same error as before.